# Scalar-valued isnull()/isnan()/isinf()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, missing-data

In Pandas and Numpy, there are vectorized functions like `np.isnan`, `np.isinf`, and `pd.isnull` to check if the elements of an array, series, or dataframe are various kinds of missing/null/invalid.

They do work on scalars. `pd.isnull(None)` simply returns `True` rather than `pd.Series([True])`, which is convenient.

But let's say I want to know if *any* object is one of these null values; You can't do that with any of these functions! That's because they will happily vectorize over a variety of data structures. Carelessly using them will inevitably lead to the dreaded "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous" error.

What I want is a function like this:

```
assert not is_scalar_null(3)
assert not is_scalar_null([1,2])
assert not is_scalar_null([None, 1])
assert not is_scalar_null(pd.Series([None, 1]))
assert not is_scalar_null(pd.Series([None, None]))
assert is_scalar_null(None)
assert is_scalar_null(np.nan)
```

Internally, the Pandas function `pandas._lib.missing.checknull` will do the right thing:

```
import pandas._libs.missing as libmissing
libmissing.checknull(pd.Series([1,2]))  # correctly returns False
```

But it's generally bad practice to use it; according to Python naming convention, `_lib` is private. I'm also not sure about the Numpy equivalents.

**Is there an "acceptable" but official way to use the same null-checking logic as NumPy and Pandas, but strictly for scalars?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scalar-valued `isinf` and `isnan` can be found directly in the [math module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html).

A basic scalar null check can be done easily:

```py
from math import isnan

def is_scalar_null(x):
    return x is None or (isinstance(x, float) and isnan(x))
```

There is probably some un-captured edge case here, but it works well enough in my usage. This is also liable to change as Pandas starts enriching their representation of "null" data in recent versions (>= 0.25).

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is wrap `pd.isnull` in a way that in case it gets an iterable it will be forced to check it element-wise. This way you will always get a scalar boolean as output.

```
from collections import Iterable

def is_scalar_null(value):
    if isinstance(value, Iterable):
        return all(not pd.isnull(v) for v in value)
    return not pd.isnull(value)

assert is_scalar_null(3)
assert is_scalar_null([1, 2])
assert is_scalar_null(pd.Series([1]))
assert not is_scalar_null(None)
assert not is_scalar_null(np.nan)
assert not is_scalar_null([np.nan, 1])
assert not is_scalar_null(pd.Series([np.nan, 1]))
```

You can then patch the actual `pd.isnull`, but I can not say that I suggest doing so.

```
from collections import Iterable

orig_pd_is_null = pd.isnull

def is_scalar_null(value):
    if isinstance(value, Iterable):
        return all(not orig_pd_is_null(v) for v in value)
    return not orig_pd_is_null(value)

pd.isnull = is_scalar_null

assert pd.isnull(3)
assert pd.isnull([1, 2])
assert pd.isnull(pd.Series([1]))
assert not pd.isnull(None)
assert not pd.isnull(np.nan)
assert not pd.isnull([np.nan, 1])
assert not pd.isnull(pd.Series([np.nan, 1]))
```

This approach will **probably break** in case of nested iterables, but that can be fixed by using recursion in `is_scalar_null`.

Comment: Nice solution +1, I adapted it slightly to incorporate `numba` for arrays / series, which I think makes sense for OP's use case.

Comment: This is the opposite of what I want. `pd.isnull` already does this by default. I want it to *only* check for whether the object itself is a `None`, `nan`, or something else that Pandas considers "null" (`inf`?)

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension to [@DeepSpace's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53101609/9209546). For NumPy arrays and, by extension, numeric Pandas series, you can utilize `numba` for JIT-compiling your loop. `all` / `any` with a generator comprehension is generally less efficient, and often prohibitively expensive when your `NaN` value is near the end of your array.

For example, in an extreme case we see a ~240x performance differential:

```
from collections import Iterable
from numba import njit

def any_null(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if np.isnan(arr[i]):
            return True
    return False

def is_scalar_null(value, jit_flag=True):
    checker = njit(any_null) if jit_flag else any_null
    if isinstance(value, pd.Series):
        return checker(value.values)
    elif isinstance(value, np.ndarray):
        return checker(value)
    elif isinstance(value, Iterable):
        return all(not pd.isnull(v) for v in value)
    return not pd.isnull(value)

np.random.seed(0)
A = np.random.random(10**7)
A[-1] = np.nan

%timeit is_scalar_null(A, jit_flag=True)  # 74.3 ms per loop
%timeit is_scalar_null(A, jit_flag=False) # 17.6 s per loop
```